# How to get the sound used for a notification inside NotificationListenerService?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am using a `NotificationListenerService` to receive notifications. I use the method `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)` to see when a new notification is, well, posted.

This all works great, however, I cannot get the sound uri from the notification.

Here is what I have:

```
int notiDefaults = sbn.getNoficiation().defaults //This is always 0
Uri sound = sbn.getNotification().sound; // This is always null
```

However, when I create my own test notification and explicitly do the following:

```
ncomp.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND); // This makes the above code yield 1 for notiDefaults, does not change sound uri but is fine I can get the default uri easily
```

```
ncomp.setSound(myUri); // This makes the above code yield the value of myUri for "sound" when notificationPosted is called
```

The main problem I am having is this:

```
int notiDefaults = sbn.getNoficiation().defaults //This is always 0
Uri sound = sbn.getNotification().sound; // This is always null
```

occurs despite the notification actually playing sound (ie, Textra) plays sound by my `NotificationListenerService` says that it does not.

However, even in my test notification, if I do not explicitly set the sound or defaults, (meaning the notification channel says its type alert and will play a sound) the `NotificationListenerService` always yields `null` for sound uri.

What I am discovering is that no matter what I do in my `onNotificationPosted` method, if the notification does not explicitly set the defaults or sound uri, I cannot retrieve them. If one uses the notification channel options under android settings to set the sound, any `NotificationListenerService` will not get the notification sound uri to use for that notification.

If I had access to the `NotificationChannel` that belongs to this `Notification` then I can determine everything needed. But, there is no method which allows third parties to get a `NotificationChannel` of another app.

This seems to be broken google code or I am missing something.

EDIT: Testing on Android 11 Samsung Galaxy S20+

Thanks all!

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: @Racker unfortunately no. I just use the default sound if one is not found in the notification. This is an error on the source code that needs to be fixed. I have no idea how to submit a ticket to Google